# Android Gradle multi-flavor variant

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-productflavors

I'm trying to build a gradle based project with flavor groups. The groups are "market" and "cost". The problem lies on the dependency management.

For example I'd like to do something like `compileFreeGplay 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'`, which is not (yet) supported by the Android plugin for gradle.

So I used a solution based on this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22584908/2904294

The solution works and fills the following global variables correctly depending on the variant being built:

```
ext {
buildType = ""
groupCost = ""
groupMarket = ""
}
```

This is the `dependencies´ section:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20+'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'

    println groupMarket + ", " + groupCost

    if (groupMarket == 'gplay' && groupCost == 'free') {
        compile files('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\adsSdks\\MobileCoreLibrary\\mobilecore_V0.9.4.jar')
        println 'inside!!'
    }
    else if (groupMarket == 'amazon' && groupCost == 'free') {
        compile files('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\adsSdks\\Apps-SDK\\Android\\Ads\\lib\\amazon-ads-5.4.78.jar')
    }
}
```

The `printlns` are all shown correctly and the code enters the `ifs` as expected. However the library is **still not included** in the project.

It works perfectly if I place it outside the `ifs` like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20+'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'

    compile files('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\adsSdks\\MobileCoreLibrary\\mobilecore_V0.9.4.jar')
}
```

Can someone with more Gradle experience point out what am I missing here? Thank you!